# Is there any way to easily gain access to "actual ground" in an IT grounding system?

Tags: ground, grounding, earth, fault, neutral

As the title asks, is that possible? By "easy access" I mean through some connection I can find inside my home, rather than burying my own grounding electrode and running wires from it to access. And by "actual ground" I mean the soil outside; perhaps that's not the right usage of the term, feel free to correct that if so.

The way I understand it there's simply not supposed to be any connection to "actual ground" (as used earlier, the soil) inside my home, but only a connection near the local transformer box (or whatever those large grey housings for the transformers are called, not the smaller ones mounted on poles) which only activates under very high voltages (surge protection).

Also, some more questions related to this that I also have, to better understand the context:

1. As long as no such connection is made, I understand it as the neutral in my home "floating" with respect to "actual ground", but does it then make sense to think of there being a voltage between the two?
2. Since there's no circuit, what exactly would happen if I connected neutral directly to ground (essentially introducing a ground fault on purpose)?
3. Would whatever voltage existed between neutral and "actual ground" quickly get discharged like when discharging a capacitor before the neutral ended up at ground potential and no more current flowed?
4. And the way I understand it from reading about it, "the first fault is free" in an IT system, and connecting neutral to "actual ground" as described above would essentially be such a fault that would temporarily render it into a TT system; is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT would be unusual for a domestic supply.  If there's a connection from neutral to ground *anywhere* in the system, including at the transformer, then it's a TT system, not IT.  If there is a link back at the transformer, then neutral isn't floating.

> As the title asks, is that possible? By "easy access" I mean through some connection I can find inside my home, rather than burying my own grounding electrode and running wires from it to access. And by "actual ground" I mean the soil outside; perhaps that's not the right usage of the term, feel free to correct that if so.

Here in the UK, it used to be common to use a metal water pipe as the ground.  That's not considered safe any more, as suppliers are converting pipes to plastic.  Gas pipes shouldn't be used as a ground.

Unless you live in a steel-framed building, there's not much else that's reliably connected to ground.

> The way I understand it there's simply not supposed to be any connection to "actual ground" (as used earlier, the soil) inside my home, but only a connection near the local transformer box (or whatever those large grey housings for the transformers are called, not the smaller ones mounted on poles) which only activates under very high voltages (surge protection).

You need to check the rules where you live.  In North America, customers are *required* to connect neutral to ground at one point in their installation.  Here in the UK, we are *prohibited* from connecting neutral to ground (but the supplier may do it before the meter if they wish).

> As long as no such connection is made, I understand it as the neutral in my home "floating" with respect to "actual ground", but does it then make sense to think of there being a voltage between the two?

If you really do have an IT supply, there will probably be some voltage, but it's undefined what that will be, and it will change if you connect anything (even a multimeter) between the two.

> Since there's no circuit, what exactly would happen if I connected neutral directly to ground (essentially introducing a ground fault on purpose)?

It will no longer be IT.  Nothing much else will happen at that point.

> Would whatever voltage existed between neutral and "actual ground" quickly get discharged like when discharging a capacitor before the neutral ended up at ground potential and no more current flowed?

Yes.

> And the way I understand it from reading about it, "the first fault is free" in an IT system, and connecting neutral to "actual ground" as described above would essentially be such a fault that would temporarily render it into a TT system; is that correct?

Yes.  But it's arguable whether it's not TT or some variant of TN.

Comment: Thanks for good answers. "IT would be unusual for a domestic supply." Yep, I'm aware; but apparently that is what we have, and has been the standard here for a long time, though newer homes are now mostly being fitted with TN-S systems. That being said, I'm still unsure about some of the answers, because while most of seems reasonable given what I've read about IT systems, most sources state that there's still a local earth electrode that devices connect to through the earthing clip on the side of the plugs and outlets, but I have a hard time squaring this with the "no earth" of the IT system.

Answer (score 0):

> As long as no such connection is made, I understand it as the neutral
> in my home "floating" with respect to "actual ground", but does it
> then make sense to think of there being a voltage between the two?

The neutral carries the current back from hot back to the transformer, and is eventually connected to ground. The resistance in the wire on the return path creates a small voltage and is dependent on the current. Any fault will produce a huge voltage so that is why we have ground. Another reason is to avoid the common mode voltage.

> Since there's no circuit, what exactly would happen if I connected
> neutral directly to ground (essentially introducing a ground fault on
> purpose)?

Some saftey equipment might not work because it uses ground to detect fault currents, this is not a good idea. It also carries the neutral current back on the  ground which isn't good.

> Would whatever voltage existed between neutral and "actual ground"
> quickly get discharged like when discharging a capacitor before the
> neutral ended up at ground potential and no more current flowed?

If you had no current on any other circuits (and by circuits, that means those outside of your home) they would essentially be the same